# how to get Git to track Emacs org-mode archives?

Tags: git, emacs, github, org-mode

I'm using Git and Emacs org-mode. When I use org-mode to archive a subtree, it goes from `filename.org` into a file called `filename.org_archive`.

In my Git repository of all my Emacs files, when I do `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` to list all the files being tracked by Git, `filename.org_archive` DOES appear on that list.

But when I look at my local repository on `OSX GitHub`, it shows me the lines of text I've removed from `filename.org` but does NOT show me `filename.org_archive` or indicate that I've made changes to it---even though that file now has the new lines that were moved there from `filename.org`.

What am I doing wrong? And what's the solution?

Comment: What do you get when you use `git status`?

Comment: ~/Dropbox/writing/ $ git status                                                                                                   18:32:43  ☁  master ☀
    # On branch master 
    # Changes not staged for commit:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    # modified:   filename.org
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: i.e. it lists changes to filename.org, but fails to notice changes to filename.org_archive

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file? If yes, what is his content?

Comment: Did you use git update-index assume-unchanged

Comment: Turns out this is an org-mode problem and not a Git problem. For some reason org-mode was putting the archive file in a different directory, and the file I was looking at was an old unmodified one. Thanks everyone for your thoughts. Now, to figure out how to get org-archive to behave!